# Issue with date parameter in Dynamics CRM 2015 sql report

Tags: sql-server, datepicker, report, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have an issue with Sql report date parameter within Dynamics CRM 2015 where incorrect date is displayed after executing the report.

[image: Before Report Execution - Selecting dates]
[image: After Report Execution - Month and day are swapped]

It does not impact the data that is displayed after report is executed just the date picker control that displayed incorrect date.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, Problem seems to be date picker format swapped from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mmm/yyyy after execution.

Did you try to change the date format & identify the conflict of formats. I would do trial from local machine or CRM settings.